# Mongodb two collections aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

players schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  name: String,
  password: String,
  country: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'countries' }]
});
mongoose.model('players', playerSchema);
```

countries schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
var countrySchema = Schema({  
  name: String,
  isActive: Boolean
});
mongoose.model('countries', countrySchema);
```

And this is my node js find query:

```
router.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
        mongoose.model('players').find().populate('country').exec(function (err, players) {
            console.log(players);
              if (err) {
                  return console.error(err);
              } else {
                  res.format({
                      html: function(){
                        res.render('players/index', {
                              title: 'Players',
                              "players" : players
                          });
                    },
                    json: function(){
                        res.json(players);
                    }
                });
              }
        });
    });
```

I want the result set with countryId and name . But I got country is null.What to do ?

Comment: Did you verify the data in your collections if the `players` collection has references to the `countries` collection?

Comment: yes. data is ok .Is there any mongo query to find in mongo shell ?

Comment: You could use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)

Comment: I am new in mongo . so can please send me the query ?

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) entirely you will see there are clear examples on how to query the two collections.

Comment: I have used $lookup but output array field is getting null..

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `$lookup` script you've run as well as some sample documents from both collections that we can test with?