# $lookup not working in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

In mongo shell I have written the following query

```
db.users.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
     from: "countries",
     localField: "country",
     foreignField: "_id",
     as: "cname"
  }
}])
```

But cname field is getting null in shell . What is the problem and how to solve ?

Comment: please add your schema and example documents of both collections and expected results

Comment: Basing from your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013289/mongodb-two-collections-aggregation) the `users` collection's `country` field is an array, you might have to pivot (or flatten) on the array first before the `$lookup` pipeline step. So place an initial `{ "$unwind": "$country" }` pipeline step in your aggregate operation for it to work.

Comment: users collection : 
{
   id : oblectId,
   name : Name,
   country : objectId
}
countries collection : 
{
   id : objectId,
   name : country name 
}
I want one object like in mongo shell 
{
  id : users object id,
  name : users name,
  country : object id,
  cname : country name
}

Answer (score 0):

What version of MongoDB you have because  $lookup was introduced in 3.2

[check this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) for more information .

and you should update your mongodb version to latest stable version for using new properties and features on mongodb

or you can use the below command in mongo shell to upgrade your mongo shell version

```
use admin

db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } );
```

hope it will work